# Prolog - Operator priority problems

Tags: prolog, operators

What is the mistake here, when the first parameter is wrapped in parenthesis, there is a priority clash with the comma operator.

I can't figure how to make it work, do you have any ideas?

```
:-op(400, yfx, [eq]).
X*Y eq R:- number(X),number(Y),R is X*Y. % eq definition

:-2*3 eq R, writeln([2*3 eq R]).
:-(2*4) eq R, writeln([2*4 eq R]). %problems when the parameters are wrapped
:-eq(2*5,R), writeln([2*5 eq R]).
:-eq((2*6),R), writeln([2*6 eq R]). %fine here
```

Output:

```
[2*3 eq 6]
ERROR: c:/users/cravs/dropbox/programming/notes prolog/prolog scripts/identities2.pl:39:
    Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2
[2*5 eq 10]
[2*6 eq 12]
```

Comment: If you want to add round brackets for bracketing, always add a space in front of the opening bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between the `:-` and the opening parenthesis:

```
:- (2*4) eq R, writeln([2*4 eq R]).
  ^
```

Without it, `:-(2*4)` is parsed as a term with functor `':-'/1` and argument `2*4` in canonical syntax.

To see how a term is parsed, try `read/1` and `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- read(X), write_canonical(X).
:-(2*4) eq R, writeln([2*4 eq R]).                           % input
','(eq(:-(*(2,4)),_262),writeln('.'(eq(*(2,4),_262),[])))    % output
```

Comment: Amazing, I remember expressions being printed like that on julia and thought it would be nice on prolog but I had never found it, thanks.